# How to create table view?

Tags: xcode

I want to create a table with custom cell and the cell should draw dyanamicaly when we add the data data to the table.

Comment: A few things: you should be much more specific with your question. What language are you working in? What are you trying to make? You should also tell us things you've tried and why they don't work. We're here to help you, but we're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about UITableViews for iPhone, you might want to check out the [documentation at Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/Introduction.html). It's really very good.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS: [TableView programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableView.html).

For iPhone: [TableView programming guide for iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I'm not sure which one you are interested in.